# Javascript returns negative number for index

Tags: javascript

Getting the negative value when i perform the onclick function in javascript

```
  function sun()
        {
            var d,i;
            var t = document.getElementById("table");
            var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
               console.log("inside............." + i);
               rows[i].onclick = function() {
               d = (this.rowIndex);
               console.log(d);
            };
          }
      }
```

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` show?

Comment: It's because onclick function is different scope and you can't access you variable d like that

Comment: As it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/tU7VR/ - can you please add your HTML. Do you get any errors on the console? When is `sun()` called?

Comment: You should *never* create functions inside a for loop, as they will no longer have the correct closure over the variables in the parent function, in this case, d, i and t. They will instead have their final values (e.g. i will be `rows.length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not sure it's what's causing the *exact* issue you're noticing, you've encountered a pretty common JavaScript pitfall here by using a closure (anonymous function) inside of a loop. JavaScript, like many other languages that support functional programming, has the convenient property that functions can "close scope" around any variables visible to them at the time of their creation. So, as you've done there, you can use the value of `d` (or `i`) inside your function so long as it can see them when your function is declared.

Something funny happens inside a loop, though: every function you create within the loop shares the same scope, meaning they all share the *exact same* copies of `d` and `i`. As a result, when you click on *any* of your rows, the values of `d` and `i` used will be their values at the end of the loop, not the particular iteration you're targeting.

This is ordinarily fixed using something known as the "generator pattern," where you create a separate function that returns new functions closed over your desired scope. For example, in your code, you might do something like

```
function generateClickHandler(i, d) {
    return function() {
        d = (this.rowIndex);
        console.log(d);
    };
}

function sun()
{
    var d,i;
    var t = document.getElementById("table");
    var rows = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log("inside............." + i);
        rows[i].onclick = generateClickHandler(i, d);
    }
}
```

The new function `generateClickHandler` returns a function itself, but the important thing to notice here is that the returned function closes over the *local arguments* `i` and `d`, not the shared `i` and `d` values used in the loop — their values get copied when you call `generateClickHandler`. In this way, your code won't be subject to strange closure effects.

Comment: A great answer to a mediocre question... well explained